# Core Data notifications with background contexts

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

First off I'm using MagicalRecord. I've just transitioned some code to save in the background using the `saveWithBlock` method. It works great but my Core Data notifications aren't getting called, specifically `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification`. I presume this is because the saves are done on a new background context but I presumed it would get called when they are merged into the main context.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If any managedObjectContext save, in whatever thread, it should trigger this notification. Please look carefully you might be observing some context, which is not saved.

Comment: I'm observing MR_defaultContext.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're observing the wrong notification. `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` does not get posted when you save changes. It gets posted when property values are changed on objects fetched from the context. If you want a notification of a save, you need 
`NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` or possibly `NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification`.

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks. I'm actually observing ```didChange``` and ```didSave``` and neither are firing.